# validating at least one checkbox is selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I'm trying to validate that at least one checkbox in the form has been checked, however it's not currently working.

This is what my controller looks like:

```
class UserExpertise < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validate :atleast_one_is_checked

  def atleast_one_is_checked
    errors.add(:base, "Select at least one expertise") unless :gardening || :cooking || :cleaning || :washing_up
  end
end
```

However, no error shows up when none of them are selected. Incidentally, if instead I were to remove the 'unless' portion of the code, as follows, an error shows all the time, regardless of how many or how few are selected.

```
  def atleast_one_is_checked
    errors.add(:base, "Select at least one expertise") 
  end
end
```

I can't get validation that at least one checkbox has been selected though, as the above does not seem to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:gardening`, `:cooking`, `:cleaning` and `:washing_up` are symbols here, they're treated by the conditional statements as `true` values. Use methods related to the attributes, just:

```
def atleast_one_is_checked
  errors.add(:base, "Select at least one expertise") unless gardening || cooking || cleaning || washing_up
end
```

Comment: thank you! sorry I can't upvote as I'm a newbie, but this was exactly what I needed :)

Comment: @chris Happy to help.